# Unindexed views v/s Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a view which contains subquery as specified witht he following SQL query on SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_Detail] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT a.ID, a.Name1, a.Name2,
       STUFF
          ((SELECT        CAST(',' AS varchar(max)) + t .Name1
            FROM            dbo.Synonyms AS s 
            INNER JOIN dbo.Details AS t ON s.SynonymTSN = t .TSN
            WHERE        s.oID= a.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Synonym
FROM    a.Details
WHERE   (a.Rank <= 100)
```

Since the definition contains a subquery I'm not able to create an Indexed view. Will it be faster to use a query instead of the view to retrieve data if my tables are indexed.Or will an unindexed view will still perform better than using a query. The view currently contains more than 50,000 rows. What other query optimizations can I use?

PS: I don't care about performance on insert/update

Answer (score 0):

A view is simply a single SELECT statement saved using a name (i.e View Name), There is no performance benefit using view over an ad-hoc query.

Yes Indexed views can increase the performance but they come with a longgggggggg list of limitations. As they are materialized and Also other queries which are not calling this indexed view but can benefit from indexes defined on this view will make use of these indexes.

In your case you have a sub-query and also using FOR XML clause, they both are not allowed inside an indexed view.

To optimize you query you need to look at the execution plan first and see if query is doing table or Clustered Index scans. Try adding some indexes and try to get a seek instead of a scan.

Looking at this query I think if you have Indexes on `TSN`, `ID` and `RANK` columns of `dbo.Details` table and  `SynonymTSN` column of `dbo.Synonyms` table, it can improve the performance of this query.

On a side note 50,000 rows isn't really a big number of rows as long as you have primary keys defined on these two tables, you should get a reasonable performance with is pretty simple query.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a performance degradation if I use a unindexed view instead of a query?